# Splinter browsing takes too long

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I'm using splinter to navigate a website, but the issue is that I have hundreds of pages with many images and it takes too long to go through all of them. I wouldn't like to change technology, but I am willing to take trade-offs like making the browser NOT download all of the images (as long as they are in the DOM, that's fine).

- Is there a way of configuring the browser or driver to not download images?
- Is there a way of making it more "concurrent" like opening up many tabs?
- Any other ideas?

Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found out how:

```
browser = Browser(profile_preferences={'permissions.default.stylesheet': 2, 'permissions.default.image': 2})
```

Works with firefox webdriver